# Using searchCriteria.creatorId in Azure DevOps git api does not work

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to query our repo with git api to get all pull request created by a certain user:

[https://tfs.XXXXX.org/tfs/DefaultCollection/Project/_apis/git/pullrequests?searchCriteria.creatorId=domain\\DEF](https://tfs.XXXXX.org/tfs/DefaultCollection/Project/_apis/git/pullrequests?searchCriteria.creatorId=domain%5C%5CDEF)

But I'm still getting pull requests from other users as well:

This is the JSON result:

```
"value": [
    {
        .....
        "createdBy": {
            "displayName": "ABC",
            ....
            "uniqueName": "domain\\ABC",
        },
        .....
        "createdBy": {
            "displayName": "DEF",
            ....
            "uniqueName": "domain\\DEF",
        },
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the `id`, not the `uniqueName`:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting results with no parameter for searchCriteria.creatorId, as soon as I put in the id shown in the result and search again, it results zero results

Answer (score 0):

To use this API,you should provide the creator UID rather than his unique name.I wonder if you know how to get someone's UID using an unique name.